# Why does the App stop working on activity change?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

first question here by a Kotlin and AndroidStudio noob.
I made an app and want to go from one activity to another. I use buttons to navigate from the MainScreen to the 2 different screens. In Main I have this:

```
val firstBTN: Button = findViewById (R.id.firstBTN)
    firstBTN.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, FirstActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Collection", collection as Serializable)
        intent.putExtra("Result", result)
        startActivity(intent)
```

collection is a MutableListOf objects called Edibles (String, Double) that I want to give to the next activity
it is then received by this:

```
val intentE = getIntent()
    var collection = intent.getSerializableExtra("Collection") as MutableList<Edibles>
    var result = intent.getDoubleExtra("Result",0.0)
```

But everytime I press firstBTN the App stops working.Unfortunately I don't even get any bug report, so I have no idea what's the problem. I thought it might be the "as MutableList" part, but I even created an element before passing to the next activity and the same happened...

Thank you already for your help!

Comment: There is always a stack trace in LogCat that will tell you exactly which line of code had what problem to cause the crash. If you don't see the stack trace, check whether LogCat has any filters turned on.

Comment: Thank you, through your help I found out that I was casting an ImageButton as a Button, which caused the app to close even before I clicked it! Thank you so much, that might have taken me even longer, won't forget Logcat anymore, that's for sure!

Answer (score 0):

This could be anything. You should provide more data.

For starters your Android Manifest. Did you put your second activity in there?
Does the call work without the `putExtra`?

Second, what type is `collection`? Is the source data class annotated with `@Serializable`? I am not very sure that `as Serializable` alone will work because there are different Serializables.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization

When LogCat does not work, check about filters. If there are none and you see any reactions, then restart Android Studio. There are some Bugs which can stop LogCat from working.

Comment: I found the problem already, it was me not looking into the Logcat and casting an ImageButton as a Button, still thank you for your help and time. I overlooked the Logcat and had my eyes on almost every other section down there...